# Listview update issue using Adapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

In my app on the screen launch I hit a web service with default city data and it return me the response. And use that to response to update listview in my app.This thing is working fine. Now I again hit another web service and fetch its data. Everything in this service is similar to the previous one so I am using the same adapter and listview for this too. But the problem is that listview still shows data from the previous web service and not the updated one. I already clear the list before filling it with data again and I alos notify the adapter but it still shows the old data. Here is the code

```
public class VenueAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    // List<InterestAndLanguageBean> interestAndLanguageBeans=new ArrayList<>();
    List<VenueDefaultBean> venueList = new ArrayList<>();

    public VenueAdapter(Context context, List<VenueDefaultBean> imagesList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.venueList = imagesList;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return venueList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        Context c = null;
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(null);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.venue_row, parent, false);
            holder.tv_address = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
            holder.tv_type = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_type);
            holder.tv_location = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
            holder.tv_fees = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_fees);
            holder.iv_venue = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.iv_venue);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }
        holder.tv_address.setText(venueList.get(position).getLocation_Name());
        holder.tv_type.setText(venueList.get(position).getVenue_type_names());
        holder.tv_location.setText(venueList.get(position).getLocation_Name());
        holder.tv_fees.setText(venueList.get(position).getVenue_fees());
        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(venueList.get(position).getVeneImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.venue_1).into(holder.iv_venue);
        return vi;
    }

}
```

and parser code

```
public void parseVenueResponse(String result) {
    if (venueDefaultBeanArrayList.size()>0)
    {
        venueDefaultBeanArrayList.clear();
    }
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("response");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String venue_Id = object.getString("venue_Id");
            String venue_Name = object.getString("venue_Name");
            String venue_city_id = object.getString("venue_city_id");
            String city_Name = object.getString("city_Name");
            String location_id = object.getString("location_id");
            String location_Name = object.getString("location_Name");
            String venue_type_names = object.getString("venue_type_names");
            String venue_fees = object.getString("venue_fees");
            String veneImage = object.getString("veneImage");
            venueDefaultBeanArrayList.add(new VenueDefaultBean(venue_Id, venue_Name, venue_city_id, city_Name, location_id, location_Name, venue_type_names
                    , venue_fees, veneImage));
        }
        VenueAdapter venueAdapter = new VenueAdapter(getActivity(), venueDefaultBeanArrayList);
        venueAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lv_venue.setAdapter(venueAdapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, why don't you use the GSON library for modeling the server responses to java POJOs ?

Comment: I don't like using library much

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add the method to set the texts on the adapter itself? then everything is going to be set on that instance and you wont get info form another place.

Comment: can give an example what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

1) Are sure you're invoking

```
VenueAdapter venueAdapter = new VenueAdapter(getActivity(), venueDefaultBeanArrayList);
        venueAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lv_venue.setAdapter(venueAdapter);
```

from UI Thread?

2)
You need to provide correct `getItemId(int position)` (if you do not have some kind of id, just return the position)

Comment: I am doing it in onPostExecute() of asyncTask

Comment: Try  venueAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after setAdapter

Comment: no difference with this too. I don't understand when I cleared the list how it still has old data

Comment: a) you setAdapter to wrong ListView b) you clear the adapter collection, but do not inform the old adapter about it

Comment: show the source code of your activity / fragment / the place where set initial adapter to listview.